# Bootstrap Grid Stacking

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

While attempting to position grid divs, I've run into an issue where elements won't float above their previous sibling.

Here is a [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MYQeaw) with the following code (in jade/sass) for demonstration:

```
.container
  .div1.col-xs-8
  .div2.col-xs-8
  .div3.col-xs-4

.container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #333;

  .div1 {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #933;
  }

  .div2 {
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #393;
  }

  .div3 {
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #339;
  }
}
```

Expected behavior:

```
[ 1 ] [ 3 ]
[ 2 ]
```

Actual behavior:

```
[ 1 ]
[ 2 ] [ 3 ]
```

Anyone know how to achieve expected behavior?

Comment: Why would you expect that? Look at it this way, the columns flow left to right but the second one is too wide to fit on the first row so it moves to the second row. Then the one that follows will come AFTER the second one.

Comment: FYI: _“elements won't float above their previous sibling”_ – I think there might be a misunderstanding of what `float` _does_ here. It does not “make elements float”, but rather specifies how _other_ content should be floated _around_ the element that `float` is applied to. That is an important distinction even though the _effects_ achieved through it might often make it look otherwise.

Comment: Sadly it looks like there's not a way to achieve the desired behavior.